# Why do number of tokens I put in liquidity pool reduce? - Impermanent loss

Tags: blockchain, defi, gdax

Why is it that when the price changes, my number of tokens is reduced and not the price of each token?

**Shouldn't the number of tokens I hold stay constant** so here I would still have 10 A and 10 B tokens?
(Price change is in percentage.)

Example:

[image: example]

Comment: Which pool are you using?

Comment: This is an example to understand how impermanent loss works, this, I believe; would happen for every pool.